# exponential equation: $6^x+8^x+15^x=9^x+10^x+12^x$

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

What are the solutions of this equation? Or at least in which interval are they? $$6^x+8^x+15^x=9^x+10^x+12^x$$ I tried to find an increasing function, or use some inequalities but I got nothing out of it...

Comment: Where does this equation come from?

Comment: $x=0, x=2$ tis a solution.

Comment: have you tried plotting it

Comment: $0$ is obvious and WA got $2$ too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $a=3^x$ and $b=2^x$ and $c=5^x$.

Then we have that
$$ab+b^3+ac=a^2+bc+ab^2$$
$$ab+b^3+ac-a^2-bc-ab^2=0$$
$$a(b-a)+b^2(b-a)-c(b-a)=0$$
$$(b-a)(a+b^2-c)=0$$

Now $a=b \implies x=0$ and $a+b^2-c=0 \implies  3^x+4^x=5^x$ which gives solution for $x=2$ only and not for any higher integer $x$ by Fermat's Last Theorem.

So these are the $2$ solutions.

Comment: Love this use of FLT !

Comment: Can we use FLT here when there is no guarantee of $x$ being an integer?

Comment: No, but there's a simple way around this: Dividing both sides by $5^x$ gives $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x = 1$, but the quantity on the l.h.s. is a strictly decreasing function of $x$, so the equation has at most one solution.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: your equation can be factorized as $$\left(2^x-3^x\right) \left(2^{2 x}+3^x-5^x\right)=0$$

Comment: How did you get this? I mean, it doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: I know this equation from Mathlinks

Comment: @S.C.B We can write the equation as: $$2^{3x} + 2^x3^x +3^x5^x = 2^{2x}3^x + 3^{2x} + 2^x5^x $$ $$\Rightarrow 2^x2^{2x} +2^x3^x-2^x5^x = 3^x2^{2x} +3^x3^x-3^x5^x $$

Comment: i think this doesn't help at all

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What is Mathlinks?

Comment: see here www.mathlinks.ro

Comment: $$x=0$$ or $$x=2$$ are the only solutions